# Remove filter from WordPress Plugin

Tags: plugins, multisite

I am using a plugin called that causes all of distributed posts to have a rel=canonical back to the source. I reached out to the developers and they told me the following:

By default, canonical URL of distributed post will point to original content, which corresponds to SEO best practices. This can be overridden by extending Distributor with custom code and removing Distributor's default front end canonical URL filtering (look for 'get_canonical_url' and 'wpseo_canonical').

Here is their code:

```
public static function canonicalize_front_end() {
    add_filter( 'get_canonical_url', array( '\Distributor\InternalConnections\NetworkSiteConnection', 'canonical_url' ), 10, 2 );
    add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', array( '\Distributor\InternalConnections\NetworkSiteConnection', 'wpseo_canonical_url' ) );
    add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_url', array( '\Distributor\InternalConnections\NetworkSiteConnection', 'wpseo_og_url' ) );
    add_filter( 'the_author', array( '\Distributor\InternalConnections\NetworkSiteConnection', 'the_author_distributed' ) );
    add_filter( 'author_link', array( '\Distributor\InternalConnections\NetworkSiteConnection', 'author_posts_url_distributed' ), 10, 3 );
}
```

I went into my child theme functions.php file and added the following:

```
  remove_filter( 'get_canonical_url', array( '\Distributor\InternalConnections\NetworkSiteConnection', 'canonical_url' ), 10, 2 );
  remove_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', array( '\Distributor\InternalConnections\NetworkSiteConnection', 'wpseo_canonical_url' ) );
```

It doesn't seem to work for me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you certain your functions.php file is being called?  Assuming this isn't the issue, your `remove_filter` statements are probably executing before the plugin adds the filters.  Look at the plugin code and find where the `canonicalize_front_end` is called and remove the filters after that.  The order of operations in WP trips up many so finding where in the process functions are firing is key.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add `remove_filter()` and have it remove the filters.

`remove_filter()` *always* has to happen *after* the callback you want to remove is added. Your `remove_filter()` call is most likely run *before* the plugin's `add_filter()`.

You need to find where/when that plugin hooks `canonicalize_front_end()` and then run your removal accordingly (i.e. at or after that).

For example, if `canonicalize_front_end()` is run at the `init` action, then you could do the following:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_remove_filter' );
function my_remove_filter() {
    remove_filter( 'get_canonical_url', array( '\Distributor\InternalConnections\NetworkSiteConnection', 'canonical_url' ), 10, 2 );
    remove_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', array( '\Distributor\InternalConnections\NetworkSiteConnection', 'wpseo_canonical_url' ) );
}
```

Comment: I found where it registered the connections using add_action('init'). So I used your approach but it didn't seem to fire and remove this filter on the front end of the site.